# bringing up different page when logged in

Tags: java, android, social-networking

let me start off by saying happy holidays to everyone!

ok i really just need confirmation and correction if needed.

**what im trying to do:**

Im using google and facebook "Log-in" feature to sign in for my app to retrieve the data needed like name email etc.

**where i Need help:**

after signing in i want another activity to be the forefront everytime app opens unless the user signs out then of course, it takes them back to the original main page to sign back in.

now im assuming this takes place in maybe the lifecycle right?

**somthing like:**

```
@override
OnResume
{
  //if user is signed in cast an Intent to automatically go to another activity?
}
```

am i on the right track on no? thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure off the top of my head how Google and Facebook's login is implemented... do they have a sample project you're using?

And yep, you're on the right track! Generally speaking you should be able to have a "Main" activity (MainActivity for this example) which checks to see if the login was successful, and if so, kicks you to the activity you want (LoggedInActivity).

This would be in the `onCreate()` or `onResume()` method of MainActivity.java

```
onResume() { // onCreate() should work, too.
   if (loggedIn) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoggedInActivity.class));
   } else {
        // send them to login
   }
}
```

If there's not a good way to check if they're logged in, you could save a boolean value or api token using SharedPreferences once the login is successful, and check that value (that'd be the value of `loggedIn`) every time at launch. You'd obviously need to clear that value any time you logged out.

Comment: oh ok good good im only using the "Login with" portion of google and facebook so im assuming it isnt to intrusive because they are both getting  along well lol but thanks for the clarification i will get to work on this